# base64 to hex inconsistent results

Tags: java, hex, base64

Yesterday, I wrote a unit test in java. The routine I was testing needed to convert a base64 in hex and back.

In my test, I used the string `myEvent=` for the base64. In hex, it becomes `9B212F7A7B`, but when I convert the hex back to base64, I get `myEvens=`.

Why is this happening? I tried different libs and tools and it always give me this result.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String data1 = "myEvent=";
        String hex1 = convertBase64StringToBase16(data1); // 9B212F7A7B
        String data2 = convertBase16StringtoBase64(hex1); // myEvens=
        String hex2 = convertBase64StringToBase16(data2); // 9B212F7A7B 
        System.out.println("data1=" + data1);
        System.out.println("data2=" + data2);
        System.out.println("hex1=" + hex1);
        System.out.println("hex2=" + hex2);
    }

    private static String convertBase16StringtoBase64(String base16) {
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(base16));
    }

    public static String convertBase64StringToBase16(String base64) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(base64));
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://rextester.com/JFDYO56442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [base64 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) says:

> When the number of bytes to encode is not divisible by three (that is, if there are only one or two bytes of input for the last 24-bit block), then the following action is performed:
>
> Add extra bytes with value zero so there are three bytes, and perform the conversion to base64. If there was only one significant input byte, only the first two base64 digits are picked (12 bits), and if there were two significant input bytes, the first three base64 digits are picked (18 bits). '=' characters might be added to make the last block contain four base64 characters.

So, since your last block (`ent=`) contains a single `=`, that means that the original byte array ended with a block of 2 bytes, or 16 bits.

- The first 6 bits were the number 30, leading to the character `e`.
- The next 6 bits were the number 39, leading to the character `n`.
- That leaves 4 significant bits followed by two 0 bits due to the padding, which should thus lead to an even number. And yet your third character is `t`, which represents the number 45. And 45 is odd. So that means that `ent=` is not a valid base64 block. A correct base64 encoder would never encode any byte sequence to `ent=`.

The number 45 is, in binary `101101`. But since only the first 4 bits are significant, A correct encoder should have taken them and padded them with two 0 bits, leading to `101100`, which is the number 44, leading to the letter `s`.

So, to recap, you would never have such a "bug" if the base64 value you're decoding was a correct base64 value.

Comment: Why `Base64.Decoder.decode(...)` does not throw an `IllegalArgumentException` since "src is not in valid Base64 scheme"?

Comment: I guess they chose to be forgiving and fast rather than to be slower by adding verifications that should normally never trigger. That, or the spec explicitely says that a decoder should be forgiving (I haven't read the spec).